# When would Mandalorians of clan Vizsla have fought the Separatists during the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, the-mandalorian

In the flashback of the attack on Din Djarin's childhood home, we see him being rescued by a group of Mandalorians bearing the sigil of clan Vizsla.

I was under the impression that clan Vizsla formed most of the Death Watch, who by and large were allied with the Separatists during the Clone Wars. When would they have been fighting super battle droids and HMP droid gunships?

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of the Clone Wars, Death Watch is allied with the Separatists.  But in Season 4 Episode 14 of the Clone Wars, we see that Death Watch are enemies of Count Dooku.  Pre Vizsla even has a scar from Dooku.  This is where I would place the flashbacks from the Mandalorian.  Plus, it was always in Pre Vizsla’s plans to make Death Watch seem like heroes.

Comment: There is no timeline associated with that scene in the Mandalorian.  It is even possible that this occurred towards the end of the war when Maul was ruling Mandalore.  He was also an enemy of Dooku and the Separatists

Comment: The armor of the Mandalorians in the flashback have blue highlights that look more like the armor used by Death Watch under Pre Vizsla.  When Maul is controlling Death Watch they wear red instead of blue.

Comment: still doesn't fit with the Mandalorian narrative from the Clone Wars.  I've asked a similar question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161011/is-there-an-explanation-for-the-inconsistency-in-the-mandalorians-between-the-cl.  Out of univerise, I am reading this as Filoni doesn't like Lucas did to the Mandalorians in the TV show and is trying to fix it.  But there is still a gap