# Why can’t The Mandalorian from The Mandalorian take off his helmet, while animated mandalorians like Sabine and Pre Vizsla can?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels, the-mandalorian, mandalorian

In The Mandalorian they make a big deal of Mando never removing his helmet in front of others, yet characters like Sabine do it casually all of the time. Is this a contradiction, unexplained, or is there an explanation?

Comment: In the Mandalorian, we are exposed to one sect and one sects rules - their rules don’t have to apply to all Mandalorians...

Comment: Highly related: [Do Mandalorians truly never remove their helmets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/223481/31394)

Comment: Also rules change over time. Out of universe: Pedro Pascal was not always on set, so they probably came up with the rule to simplify the shooting.

Comment: This kinda answers your question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/223650/92306

Comment: Sabine could have abandoned the path before and we don't know

Comment: New lore, in the EU of Star Wars there have been multiple Mandalorians who didn't wear helmet sin public at one point or another. Making me think that this rule only got established after the shows conception to give them a bit more mystery, just as many other things about Mandalorian culture have been created for the show to give them a more unique background.

Answer (score 13):

There's a couple of things at play here (note that there's a lot of spoilers here)

## Mandalorian has two meanings

In a normal world, Mandalorian would refer to people from Mandalore. In the Star Wars universe, everything is fluid. As such, a Mandalorian can *also* refer to someone who believes in [The Mandalorian Way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLDZU.gif) (I'll just call it The Way for simplicity, since that's what they typically call it, although it does have another name below).

In the series, we learn that

> Din Djarin (the namesake Mandalorian for the series) is not from Mandalore. He was saved by Mandalorians and became a follower of The Way.

## Lots of retcons

There's no way to get around the fact that [Disney keeps retconning Mandalorian canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161011/is-there-an-explanation-for-the-inconsistency-in-the-mandalorians-between-the-cl). Current canon is

> Mandalorians were a proud warrior culture that waged war against the Jedi (and presumably the Republic). Since [The Empire] dictates terms [after winning the war], Mandalorians were probably forced to disarm and shun lots of their traditional beliefs and customs.

As such, the best explanation here is that **Mandalore** Mandalorians weren't strict followers of The Way. After the Empire nearly wiped them out, The Way became a religion that anyone could become a follower of. As such, helmet removal became prohibited among its followers. *The Mandalorian* Episode 1 dialog supports this

> KUIIL: You need to drop your rifle.
> MANDALORIAN: I'm a Mandalorian. Weapons are part of my religion.

## Season 2

[Bo-Katan Kryze of Mandalore](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bo-Katan_Kryze) more or less confirms all this in Episode 11 (S2E3). She refers to Din Djarin as thus (taken directly from closed caption)

> BO-KATAN: And you are a Child of The Watch.
> DIN DJARIN: The Watch?
> BO-KATAN: Children of the Watch are a cult of religious zealouts that broke away from Mandalorian society. Their goal was to re-establish the ancient way.

They clearly have disdain for one another when Bo-Katan removes her helmet and Din flies away in apparent disgust after he dismisses what she's just told him.

Comment: Is the "Weapons are part of my religion" line really the best dialogue to support this?  There is another scene where they specifically lay out that removing their helmet is forbidden.

Comment: @Harabeck I'm trying to establish that Mando thought of being a Mandalorian as a religion. The question already establishes he couldn't remove it.

Answer (score 8):

In S02E03 - Chapter 11 - The Heiress, it has been revealed that Mando belongs to a group of Mandalorians called *The Watch*.

> The Children of the Watch, or simply the Watch, was, as recounted by Bo-Katan Kryze, a Mandalorian cult of religious zealots that followed the Way of the Mandalore, which had fallen out of the mainstream Mandalorian society. The Fighting Corps were members of the Children of the Watch but also bore the symbol of Death Watch.
>
> Din Djarin was a Child of the Watch, having once believed that all Mandalorians were like him.
>
> From the Star Wars Fandom article on [The Children of the Watch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Watch)

If you follow the link to the Way of the Mandalore, the following is being stated:

> The faith practiced by the Children of the Watch cult,[2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Way_of_the_Mandalore) the Way of the Mandalore involved protecting fellow Mandalorians but also wearing a helmet at all times.
>
> From the Star Wars Fandom article on [The Way of the Mandalore](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Way_of_the_Mandalore)